# Реализация типа-обёртки

Tags: c#, чистый-код, реализация

Помогите исправить код. Я пишу **тип-обёртку** в проекте для нейронных сетей и я хочу чтобы изменяя в этой структуре тип с **double** на **float**, **ufloat**, **double**, **udouble**, **ulong** или другой числовой, все **функции приведения** типов, **конструкторы**, **неявные преобразования** работали корректно. Пожалуйста, посмотрите и исправьте в коде некорректные реализации:

```
using System;
namespace Neuronet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип параметров нейрона
    /// </summary>
    public struct NType : IComparable, IComparable<NType>, IConvertible, IEquatable<NType>, IFormattable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Значение, выражающее тип параметров нейрона
        /// Сейчас double, вы можете сменить тип, изменяя тип value, MinValue, MaxValue, Epsilon 
        /// </summary>
        readonly double value;
        public const double MinValue = double.MinValue;
        public const double MaxValue = double.MaxValue;
        public const double Epsilon = double.Epsilon;

        #region ctors
        /// <summary>
        /// Конструктор от int
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">Значение</param>
        public NType(int v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(double v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(float v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(uint v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(Int16 v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(UInt16 v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(Int64 v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(UInt64 v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public NType(NType v)
        {
            value = v;
        }
        #endregion

        #region comparse
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
            => obj is NType check && Equals(check);

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public bool Equals(NType other)
        {
            return this.value == other.value;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is NType other)
                return CompareTo(other);
            else
                return -1; /// Неприводимые объекты больше приводимых
        }
        #endregion

        #region converts
        public static NType ToNType(int v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            return value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
        }

        public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
        {
            return value.GetTypeCode();
        }

        public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return value == 0 ? false : true;
        }

        public char ToChar(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (char)value;
        }

        public sbyte ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (sbyte)value;
        }

        public byte ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (byte)value;
        }

        public short ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (Int16)value;
        }

        public ushort ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (UInt16)value;
        }

        public int ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (Int32)value;
        }

        public uint ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (UInt32)value;
        }

        public long ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (Int64)value;
        }

        public ulong ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (UInt64)value;
        }

        public float ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (float)value;
        }

        public double ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (double)value;
        }

        public decimal ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (decimal)value;
        }

        public DateTime ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return new DateTime((long)value);
        }

        public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return value.ToString(provider);
        }

        public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
        {

            return ((IConvertible)value).ToType(conversionType, provider);
        }

        public int CompareTo(NType other)
              => value.CompareTo(other.value);
        #endregion

        #region overloads
        public static bool operator ==(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return !(left == right);
        }

        public static bool operator <(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) < 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) <= 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) > 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) >= 0;
        }

        public static NType operator +(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value + right.value);
        }

        public static NType Add(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

        public static NType operator -(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value - right.value);
        }

        public static NType Subtract(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left - right;
        }

        public static NType operator *(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value * right.value);
        }

        public static NType Multiply(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left * right;
        }

        public static NType operator /(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value / right.value);
        }

        public static NType Divide(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left / right;
        }

        public static NType operator %(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value % right.value);
        }

        public static NType Mod(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left % right;
        }

        public static NType Increment(NType item)
        {
            var val = item.value;
            return new NType(val++);
        }

        public static NType Decrement(NType item)
        {
            var val = item.value;
            return new NType(val--);
        }
        #endregion

        #region implicits
        ///// <summary>
        ///// Неявное приведение типа от int к NType
        ///// </summary>
        ///// <param name="v">Значение</param>
        public static implicit operator NType(int v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(double v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(float v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(uint v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(Int16 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(UInt16 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(Int64 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(UInt64 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator double(NType v)
        {
            return (double)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator float(NType v)
        {
            return (float)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator int(NType v)
        {
            return (int)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator uint(NType v)
        {
            return (uint)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator Int16(NType v)
        {
            return (Int16)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator UInt16(NType v)
        {
            return (UInt16)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator Int64(NType v)
        {
            return (Int64)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator UInt64(NType v)
        {
            return (UInt64)v.value;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Так а сразу использовать дженерики нельзя?

Comment: Да, она предназначена для того чтобы использовать её как тип. Если в проекте есть несколько файлов, которые используют этот тип и вы хотите поменять, скажем, double на float, вам необходимо лишь изменить тип переменной value в этой структуре и в десятках вызовов по всему проекту тип переменной изменится, не придётся искать во всём проекте где вы написали double и исправлять на float.

Comment: generics не желательно, поскольку важно в проекте указать какого типа будут, например веса нейронов. Я могу присвоить

public T weight = 34.0

И он автоматически присвоит весу тип float, как я понимаю. И это приведёт к потере точности. Помогите исправить реализацию (исходный вопрос).

Comment: @Aycon, `34.0 == double`, `34.0f == float`.

Comment: Добавьте желаемые примеры использования в вопрос

Comment: Примеры:
1) Изменяю в NType тип на double
2) 274 переменные типа NType в проекте теперь double
3) Изменяю в NType тип на float
4) 274 переменные типа NType в проекте теперь float

Comment: Я изменил одну строку, а тип поменялся у 274 переменных.

Comment: Напишите юнит-тесты для "всех функций приведения типов, конструкторов, неявных преобразований" и прогоните с разными типами value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я так реализовал:

```
using System;
namespace Neuronet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Тип параметров нейрона
    /// </summary>
    public struct NType : IComparable, IComparable<NType>, IConvertible, IEquatable<NType>, IFormattable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Значение, выражающее тип параметров нейрона
        /// Сейчас double, вы можете сменить тип, изменяя тип value,
        /// MinValue, MaxValue, Epsilon и изменив конструктор.
        /// </summary>
        readonly double value;
        public const double MinValue = double.MinValue;
        public const double MaxValue = double.MaxValue;
        public const double Epsilon = double.Epsilon;

        #region ctors
        /// <summary>
        /// Конструктор от object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="v">Значение</param>
        public NType(object v)
        {
            if (v == null) { throw new ArgumentException(Resources.Error_2); }
            value = Convert.ToDouble(v, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        #endregion

        #region comparse
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
            => obj is NType check && Equals(check);

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public bool Equals(NType other)
        {
            return this.value == other.value;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is NType other)
                return CompareTo(other);
            else
                return -1; /// Неприводимые объекты больше приводимых
        }
        #endregion

        #region converts
        public static NType ToNType(int v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            return value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
        }

        public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
        {
            return value.GetTypeCode();
        }

        public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(value, provider);
        }

        public char ToChar(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToChar(value, provider);
        }

        public sbyte ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToSByte(value, provider);
        }

        public byte ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToByte(value, provider);
        }

        public short ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt16(value, provider);
        }

        public ushort ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt16(value, provider);
        }

        public int ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(value, provider);
        }

        public uint ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt32(value, provider);
        }

        public long ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt64(value, provider);
        }

        public ulong ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt64(value, provider);
        }

        public float ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToSingle(value, provider);
        }

        public double ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(value, provider);
        }

        public decimal ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(value, provider);
        }

        public DateTime ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToDateTime(value, provider);
        }

        public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(value, provider);
        }

        public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType, provider);
        }

        public int CompareTo(NType other)
              => value.CompareTo(other.value);
        #endregion

        #region overloads
        public static bool operator ==(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return !(left == right);
        }

        public static bool operator <(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) < 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) <= 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) > 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) >= 0;
        }

        public static NType operator +(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value + right.value);
        }

        public static NType Add(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

        public static NType operator -(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value - right.value);
        }

        public static NType Subtract(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left - right;
        }

        public static NType operator *(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value * right.value);
        }

        public static NType Multiply(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left * right;
        }

        public static NType operator /(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value / right.value);
        }

        public static NType Divide(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left / right;
        }

        public static NType operator %(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return new NType(left.value % right.value);
        }

        public static NType Mod(NType left, NType right)
        {
            return left % right;
        }

        public static NType Increment(NType item)
        {
            var val = item.value;
            return new NType(val++);
        }

        public static NType Decrement(NType item)
        {
            var val = item.value;
            return new NType(val--);
        }
        #endregion

        #region implicits
        ///// <summary>
        ///// Неявное приведение типа от int к NType
        ///// </summary>
        ///// <param name="v">Значение</param>
        public static implicit operator NType(int v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(double v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(float v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(uint v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(Int16 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(UInt16 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(Int64 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator NType(UInt64 v)
        {
            return new NType(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator double(NType v)
        {
            return (double)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator float(NType v)
        {
            return (float)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator int(NType v)
        {
            return (int)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator uint(NType v)
        {
            return (uint)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator Int16(NType v)
        {
            return (Int16)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator UInt16(NType v)
        {
            return (UInt16)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator Int64(NType v)
        {
            return (Int64)v.value;
        }

        public static implicit operator UInt64(NType v)
        {
            return (UInt64)v.value;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```